# How to Drag and Drop A UIButton From UITableview Cell to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to Drag and Drop A UIButton From UITableViewCell ContentView to a UIScrollView in Objective-C. I want to drag a UIButton instance From a UITableViewCell to UIScrollView? Kindly Suggest some solution

Comment: do you mean use interface builder drag and drop?

Comment: Please post what you have tried instead of directly asking for code. We will try and fix issues/errors you face.